# 403 Error when accessing phpMyAdmin on an ec2 Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I wanted to install a LAMP environment on a new EC2 instance using Amazon-Linux following [amazon's tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html). Then I wanted to have phpMyAdmin so I installed it using `sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install phpmyadmin` and created a link to the www directory `sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin`.

Then I altered the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` file to allow access.

The current file:

```
# phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
# 
# Allows only localhost by default
#
# But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
# dangerous unless properly secured by SSL

Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
 AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
#        SecRuleInheritance Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

But still I'm getting a 403 error, when I try to access /phpMyAdmin

error_log:

```
[Thu Aug 27 13:45:47.702678 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 25763] [client 37.49.61.176:59958] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/
[Thu Aug 27 13:45:48.699611 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 25763] [client 37.49.61.176:59958] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/
[Thu Aug 27 13:49:22.181819 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 25765] [client 37.49.61.176:60222] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/
```

What else could be the error?

Comment: I just removed that alias line and it seems to have solved the problem

Comment: I have the same problem.But phpMyAdmin.conf file not found in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was fixed after I removed

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
```

from

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
```

And then don't forget to restart by using the following command

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 2):

Copy the following code in your ***/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf***

> I found it here http://howsolve.com/i-always-get-a-403-error-with-phpmyadmin-ec2-aws/

```
    # phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
    # 
    # Allows only localhost by default
    #
    # But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
    # dangerous unless properly secured by SSL

    Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
     AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
    # phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
    #
    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from All
        Allow from None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from All
        Allow from None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from All
        Allow from None
    </Directory>

    # This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
    # filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
    #
    #<IfModule mod_security.c>
    #    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
    #        SecRuleInheritance Off
    #    </Directory>
    #</IfModule>
```

Comment: @Arfan - your answer didnt clearly mention what is the change/fix you are proposing.

Comment: simply copy above code in in following path  /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
and restart the apache services